# DHIS 2.25 says "Encryption is not configured" - how do you enable it?

Tags: dhis2

In DHIS 2 version 2.25, in the tracked entity attribute screen, under the Confidential field, it says "Encryption is not configured". How do I enable this and allow for confidential/encrypted values?

Answer (score 1):

DHIS2 allows for encryption of data. This however requires some extra setup.

DHIS2 uses an encryption algorithm classified as strong and therefore requires the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files to be installed. These files can be installed through these steps:

- Download the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files for your java version of Java from the Oracle Web site. Scroll down to the "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" section. It is important that the version of the files match the version of Java on your server.

  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
- Extract the downloaded ZIP archive. It contains two JAR files: local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar.
- Locate the JDK directory of your Java installation. From there, navigate into the jre/security directory. On Ubuntu it is often found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security.
- (Optional) Back up your existing local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar in case you want to revert to them later.
- Copy the local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar files into the security folder. You should now have the following files which completes the installation. Remember to restart your servlet container for it to take effect.

  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar

  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar